# Find $\alpha$ such that series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find all positive  $\alpha$ 's such that the series
$\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((n+1)^\alpha-n^\alpha)^2 $
is convergent.
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Sure it's not $n=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $(n+1)^{\alpha} - n^{\alpha} = \Theta(\alpha n^{\alpha-1})$. Hence,
$$((n+1)^{\alpha} - n^{\alpha})^2 = \Theta(n^{2\alpha-2})$$
Now summation $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^k$$ converges for $k < -1$. Hence, we need $2\alpha-2 < -1 \implies \alpha < \dfrac12$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\alpha < 1/2$.  Here's why:

$$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^2 = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^2} \sim\frac{1}{4 n}$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Because the behavior of the summand is monotonic in $\alpha$, by the comparison test, the sum must converge for all $\alpha < 1/2$.

NB that

$$(n+1)^{\alpha} - n^{\alpha} \sim \alpha n^{\alpha - 1}$$

So that the summand goes as $\alpha^2 n^{2 (\alpha - 1)}$.  From this we see that $\alpha < 1/2$ for convergence.

Comment: This only establishes that for $\alpha \geq 1/2$ the series diverges.